Structure ROS workspace when there is multiple versions of a package
I’m working on POC ROS2 project to understand the basic concepts and see what is feasible. An important metric is that I want to be able to version my packages, especially my ROS interfaces.
I realize I can set the version in the package.xml file and use the <build_depend> attributes while building the other packages to depend a specific version. REP140
But in terms of structuring my workspace, how would this go, given I want to have more than one version of the package to be built and used in the project at any given time. Is there a clean way to clump all the versions of the package under one directory?
Example:
src
├── versioned_package
│   ├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── package.xml
├── package_a (depends on 0.1 of versioned_package)
└── package_b (depends on 0.2 of versioned_package)
        

Where do I put the src code for 0.1 and 0.2 of versioned_package and what will the corresponding package.xml files look like?
I understand that I could do as shown below, but that seems defeat the version field in the package.xml. Also not preferable since we might have more than a few versions for many packages and this could clutter the workspace
src
├── versioned_package_v01
├── versioned_package_v02
├── package_a (depends on versioned_package_v01)
└── package_b (depends on versioned_package_v02)
        

I get using version control to store past versions. But for my case, I want to understand what it means to update an interface package for one dependent package but let the other packages use the older version of the interface.
